# Check if a directory contains only directories and suppress output

Tags: bash

What I have so far is this:

```
if [[ $(find $directory -type f) -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only subdirectories and no file";
  exit 1;
fi
```

The check works, but if said directory does have files in it, I see the output of the command 'find'. I don't need to see it, I just want to know if the directory in question contains only directories, and if it does, show that message.
I put this check before a for loop over the directory, so that if it doesn't have files terminates.

I feel like there has to be a simple way to achieve this result but couldn't find anything specific to this. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `;` at the end of the line in shell. Also, `find` does
not return a number - you have to count number of matches. This should
work:

```
if [[ "$(find "$directory" -type f -printf . | wc -c)"  -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only subdirectories and no file"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! Incredibly quick answer :)
I know, it's a habit I have. I'll take the ; off.

Comment: No need to fork another subshell to pipe a `wc -c`. Just do `[[ -z "$(find "$directory" -type f)" ]]` instead. And this even work with BSD Find which does not provide a `-printf`.

Comment: @LéaGris: oh, that would in that case too. Nice idea.